# Is there any way to obfuscate API keys in a R package?

Tags: r, api, api-key

I need a consumer key and secret for an R package I am developing. It would be somewhat cumbersome for each user to apply and get their own and there really isn't a need since they will have to authenticate with a username/password to use the package functions. However, I am not allowed to share my keys in the open. Is there any way the key+secret (or any bit of information for that matter) could be hidden in my package source once it is on CRAN? I'm guessing that the answer is no but I'd like to make sure I'm not missing other ideas.

Update: The only abuse I foresee is someone extracting and using the keys in another application to max out my rate limits. But if that were the case, then I could just remove it. But there might be other forms of abuse that I am missing. Perhaps I should just let everyone apply for their own.

Comment: Define "hidden."  Then go read about "security through obscurity" at schneier.com .

Comment: Carl just got a +1. Also consider exactly how obfuscated something can be when sources are free.  But you could do something else -- mac or ip address hashed for example.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Of course I know sources are free and I generally trust people not to do anything malicious but TOS forbid me from doing it without some reasonable obfuscation. If it turns out that someone abuses the keys, I can remove them in another update.

Comment: But the purpose of this question was more to confirm what I already know and also to make sure someone else hadn't figured out a workaround.

Comment: On further thought,this is all moot because no matter how they are obfuscated, my keys would show up in the OAuth object that is needed for every single operation. If anyone wants to close it, I am ok with that.

Answer (score 3):

Well as long as you are aware that obfuscation is not security, there are some simple ways to obfuscate. You don't specify how your keys are stored, so I'll assume that they are stored in binary form in a file.

The simplest obfuscation is to `xor` with some value - I'll use "DEADBEEF" just because it sounds tasty:

```
keyFile <- "c:/foo.bin"
obfuscatedKey <- readBin(keyFile, "raw", file.info(keyFile)$size)
key <- xor(obfuscatedKey , as.raw(c(0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef))) # xor with DEADBEEF
```

Because of `xor` being symmetric, the same code can be used to create the obfuscatedKey from the original key too.

Another way is to scramble the vector. By using the random number generator with a "secret" seed (42), the key is obfuscated:

```
# obfuscate
key <- 101:110
n <- length(key)
set.seed(42, "Mersenne-Twister") # To get the same permutation
perm <- sample.int(n)
obfuscatedKey <- key[perm]

# unobfuscate
orgKey <- integer(n)
set.seed(42, "Mersenne-Twister") # To get the same permutation
perm <- sample.int(n)
orgKey[perm] <- obfuscatedKey

identical(key, orgKey) # TRUE
```

...and you can of course combine both methods...

Comment: I anticipate the OPs next question will be how to obfuscate R source code. My standard answer to that is to use ROT-13, twice.